# 'Sox' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Python Conda enviroment

Tags: python, windows, sox

I opened a new virtual environment with Conda and use pip to install the requirements.txt file of a project I cloned from Github. It has sox as well, where the problem occurs.

You can see in the image that it was installed successfully.
In the folder anaconda3/envs/my_venv/Lib/site-packages
Two folders named sox-1.4.1.dist-info and sox were installed. You can see from the image as well.

I added both files to the system path. Then when I ran the following python code to experiment in my virtual environment;

```
import sox
# get the sample rate
tfm = sox.Transformer()
tfm.trim(5, 10.5)
tfm.compand()
# apply a fade in and fade out
tfm.fade(fade_in_len=1.0, fade_out_len=0.5)
```

I got the following error and no matter what I did it didn't resolve.

'sox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
SoX could not be found!

If you do not have SoX, proceed here:
- - - http://sox.sourceforge.net/ - - -

```
If you do (or think that you should) have SoX, double-check your
path variables.
```

[image: Installed packages]

[image: Installed sox files]

Comment: See the part where it says "If you do (or think that you should) have SoX, double-check your path variables."? Do you understand what this means? Did you try to do it? What result did you see, and do you think this is correct?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  I added these two folders path to the my system path variables. Nothing change.

Comment: What happens if you try using `sox` **at the command line**, as a separate program? (SoX is not **just** the Python package; there is a separate executable program, and the Python code works by running it as a subprocess and capturing its output.)

Comment: Do not add those folders to your path. Add the folder **where the SoX application is** to your path. If you do not know where that is or what that means, *that is because you do not actually have SoX*, and need to follow the instructions at the sourceforge link.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your comments. But I have already installed SoX application and it is installed on the C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2, where I add this path to the system variable path, but still get the same error.

Comment: "Sox" is not recognized because the library is called sox